# how to append list with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, input

I have following code, that will ask user each month's rainfall, and append that to `rainfall_inch` list, and calculate `average`
but i have two issues

1) after the user enters a number and next input runs, the previous entry shows behind the next input.

```
"Enter rainfallJanuary  :  3
Enter rainfallFebruary 3 :  4"
```

and so on
2) problem is "'`list`' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" with my code.

```
def main():

    rainfall_inch = []

    name_month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]


    for item in name_month:
        x = input()
        print("Enter rainfall" + item, x, ": ", end=' ')
        rainfall_inch.append(x)
    b = [float(x) for x in range(rainfall_inch)]


    print(b)

    print("average rainfall is:", computeAverage(b))

def computeAverage(values):
    #find average of rainfull
    total = 0.0
    for x in values:
        total+=x
    average = total/len(values)
    return average

main()
```

help thank you

Comment: change `x = input()` to  `x = int(input())`

Comment: when running your code, I get a `SyntaxError` at `end=" "` - I hence can't reproduce your error

Comment: @sudonym You are running in Python 2.x, wheras the code is in 3.x.

Comment: I understand - this should IMO be highlighted somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I've fixed some logic errors with your code, Look for comments so as to see where,

```
def main():

    rainfall_inch = []

    name_month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    for item in name_month:
        print("Enter rainfall" + item, ": ", end=' ')
        x = input()
        if x == '':
            x = 0

        rainfall_inch.append(x) # you are appending here
    b = [float(i) for i in rainfall_inch] # so remove the range here, its wrong
    # range generates integers from a to b where a and b are integers
    print(b)

    print("average rainfall is:", computeAverage(b))

def computeAverage(values):
    #find average of rainfull
    total = 0.0
    for x in values:
        total+=x
    average = total/len(values)
    return average

main()
```

Outputs:

```
Enter rainfallJanuary :  40
Enter rainfallFebruary :  50
Enter rainfallMarch :  30
Enter rainfallApril :  60
Enter rainfallMay :  50
Enter rainfallJune :  30
Enter rainfallJuly :  330
Enter rainfallAugust :  20
Enter rainfallSeptember :  50
Enter rainfallOctober :  90
Enter rainfallNovember :  30
Enter rainfallDecember :  430
[40.0, 50.0, 30.0, 60.0, 50.0, 30.0, 330.0, 20.0, 50.0, 90.0, 30.0, 430.0]
average rainfall is: 100.83333333333333
```

Comment: somehow when i run it i still have error saying "could not convert string to float:"

Comment: also why it has "rainfallNovember 20 :  25,"that "20" before ":"

Comment: @RainyDay The problems are fixed now, Try running it.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed range() like this

```
b = [float(x) for x in rainfall_inch]
```

and found to be working without error